# Angular 6: lazy load a service/provider inside another service

Tags: dependency-injection, angular6, angular-providers

I am trying to lazy load a provider into a parent because of the knowledge of the child. Imagine the following:

```js
@Injectable()
export class ServiceA {
    constructor(
        @Inject(MY_TOKEN)
        private serviceB: ServiceBImpl
    ) { }

    run() {
        this.serviceB.b();
    }
}
```

`ServiceBImpl` is simply an interface

```js
export let MY_TOKEN = new InjectionToken<ServiceBImpl>('MY_TOKEN');

export interface ServiceBImpl {
    b();
}
```

`ServiceA` is loaded in the root `AppModule`

```js
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule
  ],
  providers: [
    ServiceA
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

`MY_TOKEN` is loaded in a child injector. However, I don't request `MY_TOKEN` in this component, I request `ServiceA`.

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  providers: [
    { provide: MY_TOKEN, useClass: ServiceB }
  ]
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';

  constructor(
    public serviceA: ServiceA
  ) {
    // Does not work
    this.serviceA.run();
  }
}
```

This does not work.

*Let me be clear that I do not want to have `ServiceA` in the providers at the Component level, but load it from the `AppModule`.*

Here is a test:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-u8tbwx

Answer (score 0):

The challenge with what you're trying to accomplish is that `ServiceA` is provided at the root injector, which for all intents and purposes creates a singleton. Therefore, when `ServiceA` is constructed, it simply has to work with whatever is available in that injector—if no `MY_TOKEN` is provided, then it'll break.

I'd suggest making `ServiceA` more of a factory to give you the flexibility you're looking for. Taking from your Stackblitz example where `ServiceA` depends on `ServiceAA` which depends on `ServiceB`:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ],
  providers: [
    { provide: MY_TOKEN, useClass: ServiceB }
  ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  serviceAA: ServiceAA;

  constructor(
    private serviceA: ServiceA,
    @Inject(MY_TOKEN) private serviceB: ServiceBImpl
  ) {
    this.serviceAA = serviceA.createServiceAAWithB(serviceB);
  } 
}
```

`createServiceAAWithB` would literally `new ServiceAA(serviceb)`. This pattern is perhaps similar to what the `@angular/cdk` Overlay service does to generate overlay instances in their `create` method, which is basically factory: https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/7.0.0/src/cdk/overlay/overlay.ts#L66.